# How to reduce all elements in a stream to a common field?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<Person>` and want to check that all persons are of the same `TypePerson`. Which in this case is derived by age. And if all are the same, return that common type.

The following works, but I feel it's not optimal collecting the person types to a set first, of which I then return only the first element. Could the following be optimized?

```
class Person {
    int age;
}

enum TypePerson {
    BABY, CHILD, ADULT;
}

//should check if the list contains only a single person type, and return it.
TypePerson reduceToSinglePersonType(List<Person> persons) {
    Set<TypePerson> types = persons.stream()
                .map(p -> resolvePersonType(person.age))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    if (types.size() != 1) return null; //nothing in common
    return types.iterator().next();
}

TypePerson resolvePersonType(int age) {
    if (age < 2) return BABY;
    if (age < 10) return CHILD;
    return ADULT;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the (only) reduced value, you don't need to build a set. just compare all items to the value of the first in the list, and return it if all match:

```
if (!persons.isEmpty()) {
    // get the first (only?) person type
    TypePerson possiblyOnlyType = resolvePersonType(persons.get(0).age);
    // if all items in list have same value...
    if (persons.stream()
            .allMatch(person -> resolvePersonType(person.age) == possiblyOnlyType)) {
        return possiblyOnlyType;
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Could I as well skip the first item in the stream (as it has already been evaluated)?

Comment: you can add `skip(1)` to the stream, although the performance gain is negligible

Answer (score 2):

It would be perfect if we could do

```
TypePerson reduceToSinglePersonType(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
        .map(p -> resolvePersonType(p.age))
        .reduce((t1, t2) -> t1 == t2? t1: null) // does not work
        .orElse(null);
}
```

but unfortunately, it is not allowed for `reduce` to evaluate to `null` and since the type is an `enum`, there is no other out-of-range value to represent the invalid state of having ambiguous values.

One workaround would be dealing with the ordinals, which allow us to use `-1` as invalid value

```
TypePerson reduceToSinglePersonType(List<Person> persons) {
    int o = persons.stream()
        .mapToInt(p -> resolvePersonType(p.age).ordinal())
        .reduce((t1, t2) -> t1 == t2? t1: -1)
        .orElse(-1);
    return o < 0? null: TypePerson.values()[o];
}
```

Or we use `Optional`, which genuinely supports absent values

```
TypePerson reduceToSinglePersonType(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
        .map(p -> Optional.of(resolvePersonType(p.age)))
        .reduce((o1, o2) -> o1.equals(o2)? o1: Optional.empty())
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Or we relinquish type safety temporarily, to be able to use an object of a different type to represent the invalid state

```
TypePerson reduceToSinglePersonType(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
        .<Object>map(p -> resolvePersonType(p.age))
        .reduce((o1, o2) -> o1 == o2? o1: "invalid")
        .filter(o -> o != "invalid")
        .map(TypePerson.class::cast)
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: god damn it! `.reduce((t1, t2) -> t1 == t2? t1: -1)...` je suis une idiote

Answer (score 0):

```
    TypePerson reduceToSinglePersonType(List<Person> persons) {
        if (persons.size() == 0) return null; // no type at all

        // the type, if the rest are of the same type
        TypePerson candidate = resolvePersonType(persons.get(0).age);

        // check whether other persons are of same type
        for (int i=1; i<persons.size(); i++) {
            if (resolvePersonType(persons.get(1).age) != candidate) return null; // candidate type is not unique
        }

        return candidate;
    }
```

Comment: duplicate of my answer, and an overly verbose one